# Auto-detect and display message for "give meh de codez" (and similar) styled posts

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, low-quality-posts, new-users

I was utterly shocked to find that something like (below) had absolutely *no* warning messages *at all*.

[image]

Ok, so that was an extreme example; even so, it just proves how easy it is to post something like this.

So with that in mind, can we please have some form of detection for posts that are similarly styled and display a [message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtIvt.png) (not nessecarily stop such posts from being posted)?

Comment: Why would the system warn a user with over 1000 rep against posting anything? Did you try posting this as a 1 rep user?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I've only just tested this on [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) (as an anonymous user) again, no warning. Well I can still get the "The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed" warning.

Comment: I just tried this with an anonymous new user, this works just as well although it shows you the 'first time posting' page.

Comment: This may be considered as a feature... A question of this appalling level of quality should not be blocked, it must be let through instead. So we can ban the questioner faster.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I agree; I was only suggesting that a message should be displayed, not to block the post though. Although, maybe the system could automatically flag the post for closure, for an even faster response.

Comment: The thing is that "give me teh codez" posts aren't as common as, say, "Could you kindly provide me a way to do XYZ with comprehensive examples?"

Catching all wording (the good and the bad) would be a non-trivial task.

Comment: @Qix Be that as it may, posts that are as low quality as the example I gave should have at least a basic message explaining the problem; even if it's just for bad formatting. I'm sure some clever RegExing could help solve at least part of the problem.

Comment: A filter for "give me teh codez" seems useless. Hardly anybody actually puts this phrase into their questions, they find other meandering alternatives. There are plenty of metrics for low-quality questions, but the example here is either silly or misleading, I'm not sure which. How do you propose that we instruct a computer to recognize that question *and others like it* as poor?

Comment: @CodyGray "give meh d/teh codez" was only an example. Off the top of my mind, one method for recognising bad formatting could be high levels of continuous bold text, unusual amounts of continuous punctuation, high sentence fragmentation with formatting. Remember, this is only for a *message* not an auto-delete function, so this algorithm doesn't need to be 100% spot on, better for it to be overly stringent (and display more often), than being lax and hardly get displayed.

Answer (score 10):

The question-quality filter is more general in nature than this, and is only applied when you attempt to submit the question.

As I understand it, question quality is evaluated based on statistical heuristics arrived at by comparing poorly-received questions to the kind and types of words and punctuation they contain, and assigning the post a score.  The resulting effect can, in some cases, appear counter-intuitive, since what we see as clearly bad text may not necessarily have a significant correlation to question quality.

In any case, I'm not generally in favor of automated point-solutions like this one, since they are, in fact, arbitrary in their own way, and there are an unbounded number of possible point-solutions.  Plus, blocking things based on a specific keyword comes with its own share of [pr0blems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107989).

Answer (score 9):

Well, first off... Try actually posting that:

[image: new tag warning]

Even if you fix the tags, you're still not going to be able to submit that:

[image: This post does not meet our quality standards.]

So yeah - we don't do any hand-holding here, because this sort of post is completely awful; we just block it outright. We block *thousands* of attempts to post questions like this every day, and feed even more into [/review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts).

That said, there's certainly room for offering just-in-time guidance for... *Less* obviously-awful questions. If you're interested in helping to build such quality-checks, post specific examples of questions that could be detected automatically...

Comment: "...post specific examples of questions that could be detected automatically..." so if I find a poor post that's "slipped through the net" just post it on Meta?

Comment: Please add "does anybody know" to the black-list.

Comment: @Sam A bunch of one-off meta posts is hard to track and make anything useful out of. Spend some time compiling a list and post the URLs in one question. Ideally, analyze the contents a bit and see if you detect any specific patterns first, which would help put together a feature request that goes beyond vague "let's block bad stuff" suggestions or overly specific "this probably never happens in practice, but let's block this specific colloquial phrase" kind of ideas.

Comment: I'm curious, what is the rationale for *not* showing just-in-time guidance for these types of questions? Is it a technical decision or a social one? I mean, I'm completely in support of blocking them outright, but I can't see the harm in telling people that there are major problems *before* they click the "Submit" button.

Comment: @AnnaLear Ok, thanks. I'll start now.